# MySQL Append To Year Values

Tags: mysql, json

I have following format in mysql:

```
{"2017": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}
```

Using this format i make earlier SQL Query and that works very nice (read/update payed and charge values), but i have problem when i need to append to it "2018" year so that i need to get this:

```
{"2017": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}, "2018": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}
```

I try using this code to add "2018" year:

```
UPDATE calculation 
SET payment = JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(payment, '$', CAST('{"2018": {"1": {"payed": 0,"charge": 0}}}' as JSON));
```

And get THIS:

```
[{"2017": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}, {"2018": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}]
```

And my previus SQL Query does not work because thees needs to be:

```
{"2017": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}, "2018": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}
```

How can i successfully append to get this format that i need? Rewriting previus SQL Query for this is alot of work and all is connected..so i need to append and get this format...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i do this using long way but if someone knows how to improve in one SQL query it will be fine:

```
UPDATE calculation
SET payment = SUBSTRING(payment, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(payment)-1);

UPDATE calculation
SET payment = CONCAT(payment, ', "2018": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}');
```

So first query remove last } from JSON string in payment field....and second query add new payment value for 2018 in field so i have that what i need:

```
{"2017": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}, "2018": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}
```

So to gain performance and make this faster...i need to rewrite it to be single query...

Answer (score 0):

Ok..after merging above two commands i finnaly got it:

```
UPDATE calculation
SET payment = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(payment, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(payment)-1), ', "2018": {"1": {"payed": 0, "charge": 0}}}');
```

It is not smart way but it works.